# Suitability of Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview for development

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I recently downloaded the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview, and it looks awesome. I read the fine print on the download page, and it says:

> Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview is prerelease software and should not be used in production scenarios.

I would be using **only** the C++ compiler/IDE of VS11, so does anyone know what bugs there are that would prevent me for using VS11 in a production scenario? I really want to start using it and I don't know if it's the C++ part that's not finished, or if it's just some Team Foundation Somethingorother that has nothing to do with me that's not fit for the field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The licence prohibits it. The WinDP and the associated vNext tools are free- Microsoft would obviously want you to pay. When you download the tools, you agree to the licence terms, which includes not using it in production.

Another obvious thing is that the C++ Intellisense is more than a tad buggy.

Comment: What if I'm only writing free software with it? Also what bugs do you see with Intellisense? It seems better than VS 2010 Intellisense for C++.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether your software is free or not. The license still prohibits its use for production software.

Comment: @DeCaf Well, what does production mean in this case? You giving it out to other people?

Comment: putting your software that you craft for others to use.

Comment: I'm no lawyer, so I can't answer that I'm afraid, but why would you want to use an unfinished and buggy product for production work anyway?

Comment: The "Microsoft would want you to pay" argument hardly applies to MSDN subscribers.

Comment: @DeCaf That was the question, what bugs are in it :) I don't care if there are bugs in some of the advanced features I never use. Just the C++ compiler.

Comment: microsoft doesn't want the liability.

Comment: @Seth: Try it out. If you find any bugs report it to Microsoft. That's one of the main purposes of the developer preview.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The exact same argument applies, you just happen to have already paid in advance. Specifically the C++ Intellisense loves to simply not list some functions as if they don't exist, when really they do.

Comment: @DeadMG: What I'm saying is, if it was just a matter of paying, MSDN subscribers, having paid, would be authorized to use it for production.  (Actually, maybe they are -- doesn't the MSDN license say it overrides any shrinkwrap per-product license?)

Comment: Of course it's not only about paying - I'd wager (without any inside knowledge) that it has to do with liability. Saying "go ahead and use this in production" could be interpreted as giving some form of guarantee of correctness... And I guess microsoft doesn't want the headaches that might offer.

Answer (score 1):

There is still work to be done before I would want to use the preview tools all day. The Metro stuff (C++/CX) especially is riddled with red-wigglies that claim something is wrong, but when you press F7 the solution builds without errors and runs fine. If you're using the Ultimate version, you may not find that as often, but I think you will find it. As for whether the compiler currently generates code that is incorrect, everyone hopes that it emits correct code, but of course the WHOLE POINT of the dev preview is to find out whether it does or not. So nobody can answer you. Spending some time on Connect looking at bugs others have submitted might give you a feel for whether your areas have a lot of bug reports against them. An absence of reports is ambiguous, of course -- maybe your areas are rock solid, maybe no-one on Connect is exercising them.

Comment: Well I'm not going to use Metro anyway, so that's no problem, but I do hope there isn't any code generation problems :( I actually already got an erroneous error about using `for_each` with an anonymous function, something about not being able to use templates with local structs (wasn't even using local structs), but the code compiled and ran correctly in VS 2010. I can't create a minimal code snippet that repros the problem though, so I haven't submitted it yet.